# Why retro pie isn't workong

Tags: 16.04

after setting up Retro Pie i cant find out why some ROM's don't work (the ROM's not working that i so far found- PSX, Atari 7800) is this a common problem with Retro Pie? will like some help

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but you've tagged an EOSS release that isn't on-topic on this site.  What are you using on your pie?

Comment: If you're using & thus asking about https://retropie.org.uk/ that isn't a Ubuntu product/system, thus will be on-topic on SE *Unix & Linux* or the *Raspberry Pi* section of Stack Exchange

Comment: i dont have a pie it is on my desktop and i using emulationstation that lets retropie on linux mint\

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: im using linux mint cinnemon edition